# App gets hanged after saving the image

Tags: android, service

I am capturing a image using the below code.

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imgFile));

startActivityForResult(camera, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST );
```

and inside onActivityResult if the resultCode is RESULT_OK then iam starting a Service in-order to upload the captured image to Webservice. I am able to call the Webservice successfully. But the problem is that the application is getting hanged i mean, the Activity is getting hanged. I am unable to do any actions in the Activity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think the problem is your "service" need more code about this service.

Comment: If the application is blocked, that usually means, you're doing heavy work or waiting on the main thread. Networking can't be executed on main thread, so this can't be the problem. Look for points in your App where you may are waiting for the service to finish, or else. Otherwise, provide code.

Comment: i am passing the necessary data to the service. Service is able to perform is task successfully. But the activity from where i had called the Service is getting hanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an `AsyncTask`, try a runnable.   Here's some code I did that is very similar to yours.  In my case, I was getting the intent result from a barcode scanner, but the idea is the same.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        String contents = scanResult.getContents();
        //String formatName = scanResult.getFormatName();

        if (contents == null )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), this.getString(R.string.error_no_barcode_scanned), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            GetProductInfo thread = new GetProductInfo(this, myHandler, contents);
            thread.start();
        }

    }
```

As you can see, I am passing a handler into the thread so that I can update the UI with any progress.  If you look into the thread's `run()` method, you can see data being sent back through the handler like this:

```
Message msg = new Message();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable(KEY, info);
b.putString(PRODUCTCODE, productCode);
msg.setData(b);
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

This solves both the Application Not Responding (ANR) problem and the UI update problem.

One other thing I would mention.  If you are using an external Intent to take the camera picture (such as the camera app), make SURE that the file path for saving the image is in a place that it accessible by both applications.  I made that mistake once myself.  Here was the solution I eventually came up with:

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private File getTempFile() {
   String timeStamp =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
   String imageFileName = "imgfile_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

   return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), imageFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start Asyntask instead of service to upload the image to web. Service runs on Ui Thread But asyntask run in background which will not hang the application.
 It works perfectly.

Voteup or mark true if helpful.

Comment: Can i call the Asyn Task like this inside OnActivityResult?        **new StartAsyncTask().execute();**

Comment: i had tried Asyntask(without showing progress dialog) also but facing the same problem :(

Comment: So your problem is not the service or asyntask. It is anything else

Comment: yes, application is getting hanged(not crash) after i call the Service.